# Why does FilterSecurityMetadataSource class to controller class take a longer time?

Tags: java, spring-security, timing, spring-security-oauth2

I have used Spring security oauth2 in our application. For some specific request, the time taken by `FilterSecurityMetadataSource` to controller is much higher.

`FilterSecurityMetadataSource` class:

```
public class FilterSecurityMetadataSource implements
        FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource {

    @Override
    public List<ConfigAttribute> getAttributes(Object object) {
        // ...
        System.out.println("In FilterInvocation Class");
        attributes = SecurityConfig.createListFromCommaDelimitedString(roles);
        return attributes;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<ConfigAttribute> getAllConfigAttributes() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return FilterInvocation.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }
}
```

My controller class is like this:

```
@RestController
public class MobileController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/read/bills", method = RequestMethod.POST)
       public Map method1(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
       // ...
   }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test/id", method = RequestMethod.GET)
       public Map method2(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
       // ...
   }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test/item", method = RequestMethod.GET)
       public Map method3(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

     System.out.println("Test Method3");
     // ...
    }
}
```

On our server when I check, I found huge time difference in printing two `SOUT` .

What is be the reason?

Comment: `System.out` is buffered, that might be the cause

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/buffers.html

Comment: I don't think so as this prob is specific to method

Comment: What do you mean by "specific to method" ? And what is a "huge time difference"?  Your question doesn't have enough information for anyone to be able to provide an answer other than by guessing. What is in the debug log and have you tried to check what else happens between these places where you've printed to stdout? Is there database access, for example? If you provide some basic information on the configuration you are using it will help.